# incorrect time value in LWC

Tags: apex, soql, lightning-web-components

in the query editor, I can see the time value as shown in the below image.

[image]

But when I return the same query to LWC it changes the time format to below

[image]

now if I use

```
<lightning-formatted-time value={value from apex}>
```

then instead of showing formatted time it shows integer values, could someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Formatted Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-time/documentation) displays a read-only representation of time in the user's locale format. A valid ISO8601 formatted time string must be used.

So, this tag expects the time to be in a valid time string, but `Apex` would convert this to Millisecond value.

Instead you can use, [Formatted Date Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-formatted-date-time/documentation) to format the `Long` value and display in LWC.

Refer example below:

```
<lightning-formatted-date-time value="23402020" hour="2-digit" minute="2-digit" second="2-digit" hour12="false" time-zone="UTC">
</lightning-formatted-date-time>
```

The above code will display value as **06:30:02 AM**

Comment: Thank you for your answer, could you please help me with how to convert 00:00:00.000 to the format getting from apex?

Comment: Can you elaborate your query, probably by adding a new question, with details on where you are stuck?

Comment: like from apex I am getting 27002020 and from input field of time if I select 6:30PM I want to convert it 27002020  instead of 6:30:00:00

Answer (score 0):

When i am working on a same scenario where i accessing the time from apex and console it into js it get converted into miliseconds.

to convert this milisecond time into the proper time format u need to use js functions i mentioned below:

```
 connectedCallback() {
    this.handleDataReceived(37800000);   // i passing parameter while calling method u can pass ur variable that containing milisecond time format in it.

}

// Example usage:
handleDataReceived(milliseconds) {
    const formattedTime = this.convertMillisecondsToTime(milliseconds);
    console.log(formattedTime); // Output to console
    // Further processing or UI updates can be done here
}

convertMillisecondsToTime(milliseconds) {
    // Create a new Date object using milliseconds
    const date = new Date(milliseconds);

    // Extract hours, minutes, and seconds
    const hours = date.getUTCHours();
    const minutes = date.getUTCMinutes();
    const seconds = date.getUTCSeconds();

    // Format the time string
    const timeString = hours.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
        minutes.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':' +
        seconds.toString().padStart(2, '0');

    return timeString;
}
```

[image: Here Is The Output Of Above Code]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Doesn't your Javascript produce a time string representing UTC and (probably, if you don't live in GMT) not the time of the user?! The `lightning-formatted-time` expects the time to be user time.